# Probleam using classes , array , json and php

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hi, this is my first time trying to create some code in PHP and it took me a long time but I'm able to convert data to xml. Now I need create a JSON object and it's not going well. The biggest problem is trying to create a new class in PHP (I don't know if what I did is ok or not) and if this is the correct way to attach a list. I think some of it's good but to me since I only use java and c# it seems a little crazy. I think I'm doing something wrong. The line that's showing me an error is `$array['data']->attach( new Cake($name,$ingredients,$prepare,$image));` but i don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I haven't yet written the line that includes and transforms the array into json

Thanks

```
//opens the file, if it doesn't exist, it creates
$pointer = fopen($file, "w");

// writes into json


$cake_list['data'] = new SplObjectStorage();
for ($i = 0; $i < $row; $i++) {

    // Takes the SQL data
    $name = mysql_result($sql, $i, "B.nome");
    $ingredients = mysql_result($sql, $i, "B.ingredientes");
    $prepare = mysql_result($sql, $i, "B.preparo");
    $image = mysql_result($sql, $i, "B.imagem");

    // assembles the xml tags
    // $content = "{";

    // $content .= "}";

    $array['data']->attach( new Cake($name,$ingredients,$prepare,$image));
    // $content .= ",";
    // Writes in file
    // echo $content;
    $content = json_encode($content);

    fwrite($pointer, $content);
    // echo $content;
} // close FOR

echo cake_list;

// close the file
fclose($pointer);

// message
// echo "The file <b> ".$file."</b> was created successfully !";
// closes IF($row)

class Cake {
    var $name;
    var $ingredients;
    var $prepare;
    var $image;

    public function __construct($name, $ingredients, $prepare, $image)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->ingredients = $ingredients;
    $this->prepare = $prepare;
    $this->image = $image;
    }
}

function create_instance($class, $arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4)
{
    $reflection_class = new ReflectionClass($class);
    return $reflection_class->newInstanceArgs($arg1, $arg2,$arg3, $arg4);
}
```

Comment: Can this be migrated to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), unless there is a specific question/problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are experiencing is because you are doing `$array['data']` when you mean `$cake_list['data']` so change the error line to:

```
$cake_list['data']->attach(new Cake($name, $ingredients, $prepare, $image));
```

Also a simple way to simple way to create a JSON object (or more accurately a string representation of a JSON object) is to do this:

```
$array = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'ingredients' => $ingredients,
    'prepare' => $prepare,
    'image' => $image
);

$json = json_encode($array);
```

You can also create simple easy to use objects like this:

```
$myObject = new stdClass(); // stdClass() is generic class in PHP

$myObject->name        = $name;
$myObject->ingredients = $ingredients;
$myObject->prepare     = $prepare;
$myObject->image       = $image;
```